# How to search for a string from all pdf files in a folder?

Tags: nautilus, search

I am looking for GUI tools to search for a string from pdf file contents in a given folder, like what we get in Windows Explorer. Nautilus does not have that function.

Comment: Refer to [this existing answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/184599/212930) for this task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I search a PDF file from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184581/how-do-i-search-a-pdf-file-from-command-line)